# java:comp/env is not found when using openejb in embedded mode

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi, openejb

as openejb documentation decalres

The unbreakable rules. Read these over and over again when things don't work.

1. java:comp/env is the spec defined namespace for lookup of any Container-Managed Resource
2. java:comp/env is empty by default
3. java:comp/env is read-only at runtime
   java:comp/env is populated by Declaring References to Container-Managed Resource via xml or annotation

i'm using openejb in embedded mode, DI is working fine, but i want to make lookup in pojo to get a reference to my Data Source using the standard jndi lookup as ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/DS") i tried to declare resources via xml and @Resource in a stateless ejb just to test if the env subcontext is populated but i don't know why the env subcontext is never created ... plz help

Comment: Show the relevant XML/@Resource and the corresponding error, or you won't get many useful responses.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues when I was using OpenEJB in tests. In case of embedded tests with OpenEJB you should rather look for java:openejb/ not java:comp/env

With this little snippet you can list what's registered by OpenEJB

```
NamingEnumeration<Binding> list = initialContext.listBindings("java:openejb/");
while (list.hasMore()) {
    Binding item = list.next();
    System.out.println(item.getClassName() +" :: " + "java:openejb/" + item.getName());
}
```

if you want to get to your datasource list everything registered under "java:openejb/PersistenceUnit/". most probably you will find "java:openejb/PersistenceUnit/[name-of-persistence-unit] [hashcode]" - whicho you can use later on - in a test.

hope that helps
--Jakub

Comment: This solved my issue; I'll add `javax.naming.NamingException: scheme java not recognized` which started my search, might save somebody some time.

Comment: Then why OpenEJB don't use J2EE rules (java:comp/env/)? After it is changed to TomEE+, does it still use java:openejb/ (java:tomee/) other than java:comp/env/ ?

Comment: The JNDI naming was "standardized" as late as JavaEE6 (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html) - before that that was up to the container vendor on naming. Both TomEE and OpenEJB now comply to the JavaEE6 standard and have beans lookupable under java:global/[.....]. See TomEE documentation for details http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/lookup-of-ejbs/README.html